# Не могу подключить using System.Data.Linq;

Tags: c#, linq, linq2sql

Говорит: `Тип или имя пространства имен "Linq" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Data" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).`
Linq to sql поставил, но ошибка всё равно есть.

Comment: ` Linq to sql поставил` - как? Нажмите на проблемную строку и нажмите на лампочку, что он вам там посоветует сделать? Наверно подключить ссылку на `System.Data.Linq.dll`, либо скачать его с NuGet.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, через visual studio installer поставил, а лампочка предлагает лишние директивы просто делетнуть, в NuGet не нашёл этот пакет

Comment: И как `через visual studio installer поставил` относится к вашему **проекту**? Почитайте хотяб [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/4.1.php).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну по этому сайту я и учусь, но инфу про установку взял просто с рандомных сайтов, так как вкладки assemblies в добавлении ссылок у меня нет

Comment: У вас не .NET Core ++ случаем? Если да, то `System.Data.Linq` только под .NET Framework официально выпущен.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, именно он, весьма интересно получается тогда... И что делать, есть альтернативы для удобной работы с бд?

Comment: Linq2Sql - очень древний фреймворк. На смену ему пришёл Entity Framework, А затем и EF Core. Вот последний и используйте.

Comment: Смотря что вы подразумеваете под "удобной работой". Для одних задач я бы взял linq2db, для других - Dapper (с расширениями).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нужно брать значения из бд и пихать их в listview, ну и добавлять новые записи по мере необходимости

Comment: @Vlabey приведите пример кода, который хотите выполнить, у меня работает, .Net Core 3.1. Использую using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; using System.Linq;

Comment: @Blackmeser Вы путаете `Linq2Sql` и `Entity Framework`. Хотите код - ссылка от меня (3 коммент), пробуйте это реализовать на Core (без сторонних библиотек!).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ``var ** = from ** in ** where (***) select **;`` это и есть Linq-запрос, разве нет?

Comment: @Blackmeser Сейчас вы начинаете путать `LINQ` и `Linq2Sql`, второй создан для управления базой при помощи запросов, через него создается свой коннект (`var db = new DataContext(connectionString);`), через него получаются таблицы из базы (`var users = db.GetTable<User>();`), это не запросы LINQ, это старый аналог EF.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть ли разница при чтении данных из БД при Linq2Sql и LINQ+EFCore?

Comment: @Blackmeser Хм, а есть ли разница между .Net Framework 4 и .NET5?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ .NET5 лучше?

Comment: @Blackmeser Ну а вы как думаете? В 4 фрейме старый c#, без кучи наворотов (например async/await из коробки), а в .net5 последняя версия языка со всеми нововведениями. Не, может вы ретрофил и вам старое нравиться больше, я не знаю, но я лично за новое) Ну а `Linq2Sql` уже давно устарел, на его замену пришел EF и тут как бы ответ на вопрос "что лучше" я думаю аналогичен, нравиться старое - дерзайте, но скорей всего потеряете много наворотов. И да, я чет не пойму к чему этот разговор? Вы не знаете что выбрать или что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не ретрофил, актуальные фреймворки для меня: .NetF4.7, .NetF4.8, .NETCore3.1, ознакомиться с .NET5 к сожалению пока не предоставлялось возможности, однако EFCore5 удалось заценить - и я в восторге, удобные логи, булк-инсерты с локальной чисткой из коробки, к сожалению возникли проблемы с переносом кода с EFCore3 в адекватный срок, пришлось отказаться =( ... Я в том смысле что, хоть с Linq2Sql сталкивался раз, но особых отличий от EF не увидел, тот-же самый linq синтаксис можно использовать и с EF. Я использую linq с EF и вижу подобный Linq2Sql только в более крутой обёртке.